# Is there a way to attach with VS2013 to the application under focus?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

We are developing a Prism application and starting the application under the debugger is pretty slow due to the loading modules procedure so we start the application and later on we attach to it.

Is there a way (macro, plugin, external tool) to attach to the application that is currently under focus? That would be very convenient.

Comment: You've got a big Lego box, just snap the pieces together.  RegisterHotkey + GetForegroundWindow + GetWindowThreadProcessId, then EnvDTE to start VS and attach the debugger with Process.Attach().  Don't forget to add a bit of common sense, attaching isn't faster.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Anyway attaching is faster than running inside the debugger as there is no loading of dlls while you are already attached. This makes really a big difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Hans advice I've created a tool that exactly does that:

https://attacher.codeplex.com/

I hope it helps someone with the same need.

Answer (score 0):

According to some Research and my experience, it is not possible to attach the Debugger to the process whose window is in foreground. What may be the best solution for you, my friend, is the **Just - In - Time Debugger**. You can find more info here :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx

If you configure your application to use JIT, every time an error occurs, the following window will pop up : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCBKq.png

Comment: Thanks but I want to debug even if no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: You could produce an exception in the main method to force the window to pop up. It might be a little bit unclean, as you have to remember to remove the code when releasing the application, but it is afaik the closest solution for your needs.